# CUDA parallel program flow for Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: c++, cuda

the code here is a cuda code and is meant to find shortest pair path using Dijkstra's algorithm.

My code logic works perfectly in a c program, not in Cuda. I'm using 1 block with N threads, N being user entered.

First doubt, every thread has their own copy of variables except the shared variable temp. Correct ?

When i print the results I'm storing all values in array d and print its value which is zero for all. This is possible only if the flow of control does not enter loop after s = threadIdx.x.

Please help, have been debugging this since last 24 Hrs.

Given Input is:

> Number of vertices: 4
>
> enter the source,destination and cost of the edge\n Enter -1 to end
>   Input\n Edges start from Zero : 0 1 1
>
> enter the source,destination and cost of the edge\n Enter -1 to end
>   Input\n Edges start from Zero : 0 2 5
>
> enter the source,destination and cost of the edge\n Enter -1 to end
>   Input\n Edges start from Zero : 0 3 2
>
> enter the source,destination and cost of the edge\n Enter -1 to end
>   Input\n Edges start from Zero : 1 3 4
>
> enter the source,destination and cost of the edge\n Enter -1 to end
>   Input\n Edges start from Zero : 2 3 7
>
> enter the source,destination and cost of the edge\n Enter -1 to end
>   Input\n Edges start from Zero : -1 -1 -1

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#define nano 1000000L

__global__ void dijkstras(int *a, int *b, int *n)
{
    int i;
    int d[10],p[10],v[10];
    // d stores distnce/cost of each path
    // p stores path taken
    // v stores the nodes already travelled to
    int k,u,s;
    int check =0;

    // shared memory on cuda device
    __shared__ int temp[20];
    for(i=0; i < (*n)*(*n); i++)
    {
        temp[i] = a[i];
    }
    check = check + 1;
    __syncthreads();

    // were passing int s -- node from which distances are calculated
    s = threadIdx.x;
    for(i=0; i<(*n); i++)
    {
        d[i]=temp[s*(*n)+i];
        if(d[i]!=9999)
            p[i]=1;
        else
            p[i]=0;
        v[i]=0;
    }
    p[s]=0;
    v[s]=1;
    for(i=0; i<((*n)-1); i++)
    {
    // findmin starts here
        int i1,j1,min=0;
        for(i1=0;i1<(*n);i1++)
        {
            if(v[i1]==0)
            {
                min=i1;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j1=min+1;j1<(*n);j1++)
        {
            if((v[j1]==0) && (d[j1]<d[min]))
                min=j1;
        }
        k = min;
    // findmin ends here
        v[k]=1;
        for(u=0; u<(*n); u++)
        {
            if((v[u]==0) && (temp[k*(*n)+u]!=9999))
            { 
                if(d[u]>d[k]+temp[k*(*n)+u])
                {
                    d[u]=d[k]+temp[k*(*n)+u];
                    p[u]=k;
                }
            }
        }
    //storing output
        int count = 0;
        for(i = (s*(*n)); i< (s+1) * (*n); i++)
        {
            b[i] = d[count];
            count++;
        }
    }
    *n = check; 
}



main()
{
    int *a, *b, *n;
    int *d_a, *d_b, *d_n;
    int i,j,c;
    int check = 0;
    printf("enter the number of vertices.... : ");
    n = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    scanf("%d",n);
    int size = (*n) * (*n) * sizeof(int);

    //allocating device memory
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_n, sizeof(int));

    a = (int*)malloc(size);
    b = (int*)malloc(size);

    check = check +1;
    for(i=0; i<(*n); i++)
        for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
            if(i==j)
                a[(i*(*n) + j)]=0;
            else
                a[(i*(*n) + j)]=a[(j*(*n) + i)]=9999;

    printf("\nInitial matrix is\n");
    for(i=0;i<(*n);i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<(*n);j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[i*(*n)+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n enter the source,destination and cost of the edge\n Enter -1 to end Input\n Edges start from Zero : \n");
        scanf("%d %d %d",&i,&j,&c);
        if(i==-1)
            break;
        a[(i*(*n) + j)]=a[(j*(*n) + i)]=c;
    }

    printf("\nInput matrix is\n");
    for(i=0;i<(*n);i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<(*n);j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[i*(*n)+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    check = check +1;
    // copying input matrix to device
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_n, n, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    check++;
    struct timeval start,stop;
    double time;
    int N = *n;
    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
    dijkstras<<<1,N>>>(d_a, d_b, d_n);
    gettimeofday(&stop,NULL);
    time=(double)(stop.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)+(double)(stop.tv_usec-start.tv_usec)/(double)nano;
    printf("\n TIME TAKEN: %lf\n",time);
    check++;

    // copying result from device to host
    cudaMemcpy(b, d_b, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(n, d_n, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    check++;
    //  printing result
    printf("the shortest paths are....");
    for(i=0; i<(N); i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<(N); j++)
        {
            if(i != j)
                printf("\n the cost of the path from %d to %d = %d\n",i,j,b[i*(N) + j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("your debug value of check in main is %d\n",check);  //5

    printf("your debug value of check in device is %d\n",*n);       // 1+ 7+ 10

    free(a); free(b);free(n);
    cudaFree(d_a); cudaFree(d_b);cudaFree(d_n);
}
```

[image: Output of this code]

Comment: Where's the cuda code? Where's the c code? Where's the SSCCE and expected result?

Comment: @ChristianSarofeen added the c and cuda code also the output i get. The expected output is the shortest path values which depend on user input but it wont be zero, not all

Comment: Before downvoting please see if u even understand the problem at hand

Comment: Can you provide all the input you used, please?

Comment: @ChristianSarofeen added the given input

Comment: @nik: you had a glaring problem with inputs to the kernel (since fixed) which meant that the kernel could never have run correctly. And yet your screenshot hasn't been updated, which implies that nothing changed. Is that the case? Are you certain your CUDA installation actually works? Your host code contains no API error checking. Are you certain that there are not errors from the CUDA runtime before or after the kernel call?

Comment: @talonmies Cuda installation is working properly, I had used it previously for small hello World programs. And there are no errors during run-time on or before kernel-call.

Comment: @nik: When I finally got around to compiling and running the code you have in your question, it produced reasonable looking output, not all zeros like your screenshot. So if it produces zero output for you, then you have a problem which I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @talonmies Finally i got it. Thanks man. The gpu is on the server for me and whenever i compiled and ran it gave me the same output bcoz the server was down and it returned me the previous output. The main error was not assigning d_n in kernel. Thank you for being patient and u were right it deserves downvotes. Please post your comment as answer, so that i can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this problem was supplying an uninitialised device variable as a kernel argument. In this kernel call:

```
dijkstras<<<1,N>>>(d_a, d_b, d_n);
```

`d_n` had been allocated memory, but never assigned a value, resulting in undefined behaviour within the kernel.

I would contend this proved hard for the original poster to detect because of a poor design decision in the kernel itself. In this prototype:

```
__global__ void dijkstras(int *a, int *b, int *n)
```

`n` was being used as both an input and an output with two completely different meanings, which made it far harder to detect the problem with the call. If the prototype was:

```
__global__ void dijkstras(int *a, int *b, int n, *int check)
```

then the role of `n` and `check`would be far clearer, and likelihood of making a mistake when calling the kernel and missing it when debugging would be lessened.